# Issue instantiating bean - verify error

Tags: java, spring, initialization, javabeans, verifyerror

I have the following problem: I have a bean (named ImageStorageService), and I want to instantiate that bean in a servlet using the following code

```
WebApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(httpSession
            .getServletContext());
IImageStorageService dataService = (IImageStorageService) context
            .getBean("ImageStorageService");
```

obviously the bean class implements IImageStorageService.

The problem is that when these lines are executed, the following error is throwed:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: myproject/myclass/ImageStorageService, method: writePdfFile signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lmyproject/myobjects/IObject;)Ljava/io/File;) Call to wrong initialization method
```

Does anyone know which is the problem? Thanks so much

Edit

Bean declaration

```
<bean id="ImageStorageService" scope="session"
    destroy-method="clean"
    class="myproject.myclass.ImageStorageService">
    <property name="objectService" ref="SuperUserObjectService" />
    <property name="dataDictionaryService" ref="DataDictionaryService" />
    <property name="runQueryService" ref="RunQueryService" />
    <property name="status" ref="ImagesUploadStatus" />
</bean>
```

Class

```
[...]
package myproject.myclass;
[...]
public class ImageStorageService implements IImageStorageService {
private IRunQueryService    runQueryService;
private IObjectService                              objectService;
private IDataDictionaryService                      dataDictionaryService;
private ImagesUploadStatus                          status;

[...]
public File writePdfFile(String idPlico, String userId) throws Exception {
    return writePdfFile(idPlico, userId, false, 0, 0, 0.0, null);
}

@Override
public File writePdfFile(String idFascicolo, String userId, boolean discardBlankPages, int verticalOffset,
        int horizontalOffset, double threshold, IObject fileInfo) throws Exception {
    File pdfFile;
    [...]
    //pdfFile Elaboration
    [...]
    return pdfFile;
    }
    [...]
}
```

Full stack trace

```
java.lang.VerifyError: (class: myproject/myclass/ImageStorageService, method: writePdfFile signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lmyproject/myobjects/IObject;)Ljava/io/File;) Call to wrong initialization method
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:67)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:332)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:43)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:332)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:43)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
at myproject.myfilters.myFilter.doFilter(myFilter.java:76)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

Comment: Can you show us the bean declaration and the implementation class?

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the question

Comment: Please post full stacktrace.

Comment: I edited the question and posted the full stacktrace

Comment: The method in the error seems to be different than the one you've shown us.

Comment: this is another big problem... I'm not able to understand why that method (with 3 parameters) is showed in the log... I'm 100% sure that the code is the one I wrote

Answer (score 1):

Obviously not a long term solution, but you could just bypass class verification all together by adding `-noverify` to your command line.  You may also want to try doing a clean build.